# mkimage: Can't read mydir: No such device

Tags: linux, filesystems, u-boot

I want to convert the contents of a directory into a file with the **u-boot format**. To achieve this, I have used the **mkimage** tool, but I am encountering the following error (The directory 'mydir' exists):

```bash
$ mkimage -A powerpc -O linux -T kernel -C gzip -a 0x00000000 -e 0x00000000 -n "Linux" -d mydir file.uboot
mkimage: Can't read mydir: No such device
```

If my tool selection is incorrect or if I am issuing the command incorrectly, I would appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood what the `-d` switch does.

From the man page...

```
-d [image data file]
    Use image data from 'image data file'.
```

It is looking for a single file, not a directory, and that image data file is an initrd file.

To create the initrd file, use `mkinitrd`.